# JNI. different behavior between different Android OS versions

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, jnienv

my application runs following code :

```
void BmrDeviceInfo_convertToC(JNIEnv *pEnv, jobject jBmrDeviceInfo, BmrDeviceInfo& cBmrDeviceInfo){

__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "BEAMER_JNI", "g_classBmrDeviceInfo is = %s", (g_classBmrDeviceInfo == NULL) ? "NULL" : "OK"); //g_classBmrDeviceInfo is initialize on JNI_OnLoad

jfieldID fieldName = pEnv->GetFieldID(g_classBmrDeviceInfo, "m_strName", "Ljava/lang/String;"); // OK for Android 4.2 and crash for Android 3.1 or less

..................................
}
```

And LogCat output for crash case:

```
04-17 16:28:44.118: I/BEAMER_JNI(446): g_classBmrDeviceInfo is = OK
04-17 16:28:44.118: W/dalvikvm(446): JNI WARNING: 0x4053dc70 is not a valid JNI reference
04-17 16:28:44.118: W/dalvikvm(446):              in Lcom/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/controller/CoreController;.Init (Lcom/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/listviews/DeviceInfo;Ljava/lang/String;)I (GetFieldID)
04-17 16:28:44.118: I/dalvikvm(446): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
04-17 16:28:44.118: I/dalvikvm(446):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4001f1a8 self=0xce48
04-17 16:28:44.118: I/dalvikvm(446):   | sysTid=446 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345006528
04-17 16:28:44.118: I/dalvikvm(446):   | schedstat=( 276745040 468907344 84 )
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907832/jni-local-vs-global-reference-is-not-a-valid-jni-reference

Comment: Looks like a lot changed 4 1 the implementation class changed from c https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/gingerbread/vm/Jni.c to c++ https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/master/vm/Jni.cpp and there are a lot more changes as well. It looks like the earliest version for this was somewhere around 4.1.1. This may somewhat explain your issue. Now I am not a great C guy so maybe looking through it you can see the difference. Nothing pops out to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JNI functions that accept objects require local or global refs.  Pre-ICS these were raw pointers, but in ICS that changed to a table index system.

You don't say what version was used to generate the output in the question.  The hex value 0x4053dc70 looks like a raw pointer, so I'm assuming this is pre-ICS.  Looking at the error message, it appears that `g_classBmrDeviceInfo` is invalid; a common way to get this wrong is to fail to use `NewGlobalRef` to convert a local reference to a global reference.

Generally speaking, JNI became *more* strict in ICS, so it's peculiar that this would succeed in 4.x but fail in 3.x, unless you're playing around with weak globals.

Comment: I'm not sure I am following this myself, do you know where this changed in the source?

Comment: NM this explains it a little more... http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/jni-local-reference-changes-in-ics.html. So basically he was using a ref and when he tried to access it later (on pre-ICS) the object had already been moved by the GC and therefor was invalid. Is that basically it?

Comment: The Dalvik GC, up through at least Jellybean, does not move objects around.  Class objects are never discarded, so this failure seems like a bad global or just a completely bad pointer.  The pre-ICS CheckJNI implementation tried to check the validity of objects by searching for the references in global and local ref tables, but it was possible to "fake" this out.  The >= ICS "indirect reference" approach is more accurate, and since it's no longer handing out raw pointers it's much easier to allow the GC to move objects (which was the primary motivation for the work).